For function definition, what is the difference between using partial application, a lamba expression or put the arguments next to the name?
What are the differences between the three syntaxes
funName l = map fun l
funName = \ l -> map fun l
funName = map fun

In general it does the same thing however in some cases it differs.
The following code works fine:
class Eval a b where
    eval :: a -> b

mapEval l = map eval l

And I get the correct type for my function:
mapEval :: Eval a b => [a] -> [b]

However in the two following cases, it won't compile.

With partial application

class Eval a b where
    eval :: a -> b

mapEval = map eval


With lambda

class Eval a b where
    eval :: a -> b

mapEval = \ l -> map eval l

And I can't figure out why.
But when I explicitely give the expected type with
mapEval :: Eval a b => [a] -> [b]

then it works.
I tried the three approaches to do the same thing. I was expecting them to be logicaly equivalent but some compile and other won't.

Please add compilation errors.

In Haskell, "doesn't work" is often accompanied by informative error messages. When asking for feedback, you should provide the error message you received. Especially when the error message talks about things like the "monomorphism restriction" that don't mean anything to you yet.

Surprisingly, it seems like GHC 9.6.5's error message doesn't mention the monomorphism restriction in this case.

Hmm. The monomorphism restriction is certainly the main thing beginners need to know about on this topic, but there could have been a full answer to the literal question here, touching on the circumstances where the arity can make a difference to sharing or performance as well. If someone did write such an answer, this question wouldn't be a duplicate of "What is the monomorphism restriction?"

@Ben The marked duplicate discusses that, actually; scroll down to the section labelled "Rationale". It really is a quite comprehensive answer.

@DanielWagner Yes that answer is great, but it's talking about it as rationale for the monomorphism restriction. The MR (or even defaulting or type classes) aren't involved all of the time that arity affects things (even though those situations are unlikely to be something a non-expert really needs to worry about), so I thought there could be room for a more general answer (referring to that one for the canonical more details on the MR). Whether that belongs here or not depends on whether you interpret the question as about the difference in general, or about the OP's specific examples.
